# Can you use a string value as a page for a fixture?

Tags: testcafe

I would like to use string values as my Testcafe pages, is that possible?

```js
fixture('My project')
  .page('<body>Hello World</body>')

test('Something', (t) => {
  // test code
})
```

I have tried using a `clientScript({ content: 'document.write('Hello World') '})` But it either doesn't work or has issues with escaping quotes.

Can TestCafe do this?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter of the ["Fixture.page"](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402778/reference/test-api/fixture/page) method is intended for passing the URL of a tested web page. As a workaround, generate a temporary ".html" file for testing and pass the generated file's path to the "Fixture.Page" method via the "file://" scheme.